# Strings from an alphabet of $k$ symbols with no consecutive repeated symbols?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\Sigma = \{1,\cdots,k\}$ be an alphabet with $k$ characters. Consider the set of all strings such that no consecutive entries are the same character. Let $F(n_1,\cdots,n_k)$ count the number of such strings with exactly $n_1$ 1's, $n_2$ 2's,and so on.

I'm trying to find a formula, or perhaps a generating function for the number of such strings. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect set-up for the Goulden-Jackson cluster method. See [this paper](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/gj.html) by Zeilberger and Noonan and its accompanying Maple programs. In particular, there's a short section on page 12 "Keeping track of letters as well" that describes how to obtain generating functions for counting words of a specified length that avoid a collection of bad words and have a specific number of each letter in the alphabet. Additionally, their Maple subroutine "GJgfDetail" gives a generating function for seemingly exactly what you're asking.